# I’ve wrote that code using UIAlertController, what I should change to make it works with UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I’ve wrote that code using UIAlertController, what I should change to make it works with UIViewController?
Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
      super.viewDidLoad()
      view.backgroundColor = .white
        
      view.addSubview(tableView)
      tableView.dataSource = self
      Preformatted texttableView.delegate = self
        
    } 
}
```

Here is the part to show UIAlertController and I need change something bellow it to open ViewController.

```
extension SecondViewController: TableViewCellDelegate{
    func tableViewCellDidTapItem(with viewModel: TileCollectionViewCellModel) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: viewModel.name,
                                      message: "",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismis",
                                      style: .cancel,
                                      handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here is a part of my class for cell of objects. When I click on each of them, I need to see UIViewController instead of UIMessageAllert

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {

func tableViewCellDidTapItem(with viewModel: TileCollectionViewCellModel)
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]
    
    delegatee?.tableViewCellDidTapItem(with: viewModel)
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking for. Your `tableViewCellDidTapItem()` method creates and displays a `UIAlertController`. If you want it to instead display some other type of view controller, then create and display the other type of view controller instead. You display a `UIAlertController` modally. Do you also want your new view controller to be displayed modally?

Comment: First you have to create another View Controller that to be presented instead of UIAlertController. 
let vc = NewViewC();

present(vc, animated: true) // simple